# POST Binary (video) File Using Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a working bit of PHP code that uploads a binary to a remote server I don't have shell access to. The PHP code is:

```php
function upload($uri, $filename) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@' . $filename));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

This results in a header like:

```
HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXXX
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 208045596
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------360aaccde050
```

I'm trying to port this over to python using requests and I cannot get the server to accept my POST. I have tried every which way to use requests.post, but the header will not mimic the above.

This will successfully transfer the binary to the server (can tell by watching wireshark) but because the header is not what the server is expecting it gets rejected. The response_code is a 200 though.

```
files = {'bulk_test2.mov': ('bulk_test2.mov', open('bulk_test2.mov', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

The requests code results in a header of:

```
HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXX
Content-Length: 160
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=250852d250b24399977f365f35c4e060
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.1.0

--250852d250b24399977f365f35c4e060
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bulk_test2.mov"; filename="bulk_test2.mov"


--250852d250b24399977f365f35c4e060--
```

Any thoughts on how to make requests match the header that the PHP code generates?

Comment: Rejected *and* the response code is 200? Presumably an error message page is returned?

Comment: I notice that your `Content-Length` is only 160 bytes.. That's exactly the size of the multipart boundaries and metadata plus newlines. **Your file appears to be empty**.

Comment: So if I use ` res = requests.post(url, data=open_file,  headers={'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------360aaccde050'})` I get `Content-Length: 208045390`, which is accurate. But the header is again different than what the server is expecting

Answer (score 6):

There are two large differences:

1. The PHP code posts a field named `file`, your Python code posts a field named `bulk_test2.mov`.
2. Your Python code posts an *empty* file. There Content-Length header is 160 bytes, exactly the amount of space the multipart boundaries and `Content-Disposition` part header take up. Either the `bulk_test2.mov` file is indeed empty, or you tried to post the file multiple times without rewinding or reopening the file object.

To fix the first problem, use `'file'` as the key in your `files` dictionary:

```
files = {'file': open('bulk_test2.mov', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I used *just* the open file object as the value; `requests` will get the filename directly from the file object in that case.

The second issue is something only you can fix. Make sure you don't *reuse* `files` when repeatedly posting. Reopen, or use `files['file'].seek(0)` to rewind the read position back to the start.

The `Expect: 100-continue` header is an optional client feature that asks the server to [confirm that the body upload can go ahead](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3); it is *not* a required header and any failure to post your file object is not going to be due to `requests` using this feature or not. If an HTTP server were to misbehave if you don't use this feature, it is in violation of the HTTP RFCs and you'll have bigger problems on your hands. It certainly won't be something `requests` can fix for you.

If you do manage to post actual file data, any small variations in `Content-Length` are due to the (random) boundary being a different length between Python and PHP. This is *normal*, and not the cause of upload problems, unless your target server is extremely broken. Again, don't try to fix such brokenness with Python.

However, I'd assume you overlooked something much simpler. Perhaps the server blacklists certain `User-Agent` headers, for example. You could clear some of the default headers `requests` sets by using a [`Session` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```
files = {'file': open('bulk_test2.mov', 'rb')}
session = requests.Session()
del session.headers['User-Agent']
del session.headers['Accept-Encoding']
response = session.post(url, files=files)
```

and see if that makes a difference.

If the server fails to handle your request because it fails to handle [HTTP persistent connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), you could try to use the session as a context manager to ensure that all session connections are closed:

```
files = {'file': open('bulk_test2.mov', 'rb')}
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.post(url, files=files, stream=True)
```

and you could add:

```
response.raw.close()
```

for good measure.

Comment: So the above creates a header like                                      Content-Length: 208045540
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=bd19b64db83e4ebbaadc4835f9727856
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.1.0

--bd19b64db83e4ebbaadc4835f9727856
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="bulk_test2.mov"                                                 Which is different from what I need (shown below)                            
Content-Length: 208045596
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/fo...

Comment: Don't fixate too much on *precise* headers! `Expect: 100-continue` is not a required header, and the only thing that does is pause uploading the body until the server says it is fine to upload the body. If your HTTP upload fails because that header is missing your server has bigger problems than just this post.

Comment: And the 16 bytes content length difference is entirely explained by the fact that the (correctly generated) multipart boundaries differ by 8 characters between PHP and Python. That is never going to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The _only_ reason I'm so focused on the headers is the destination seems to rely on them for logic in their code _after_ the POST completed. If my header is not identical to the PHP generated one, the server will not process the file.

Comment: @user3524641: I **very much doubt that**. The only differences that could possible have an influence are the `User-Agent` and `Accept-Encoding` headers here, really.

Comment: @user3524641: added how you'd clear the default `User-Agent` and `Accept-Encoding` headers to the post.

Comment: Turns out it's related to requests not closing the connection, which is how the server starts the ingest process. Working though that in requests now.

Comment: @user3524641: set `keep_alive` to `False` on the session then.